# ¿Cómo saber el total de registros de una tabla Mysql sin recorrer toda la tabla?

Tags: php, mysql

Solo quería saber si hay alguna  forma de acceder al total de registros de una tabla  en  `mysql` sin tener que recorrer toda la tabla.

La verdad no se si existe un método, solo se me ocurrió pensar de que el sistema guardaría información  sobre las tablas en algún lado y a lo mejor sea posible acceder al total previamente guardado por `mysql`...  no se me imagino algo así de que cuando se hace un `insert` internamente `mysql` guarda información sobre esa consulta y con ello se  recalcula el nuevo total de esa tabla y se guarda en algún lado.

Aviso que es lo  que pienso no se si exista algo así, pero si alguien sabe algo por favor que me ayude gracias :).

Solo quiero poder acceder a un total sin recorrer toda la tabla eso nomas gracias.

Comment: solo quieres contar el número de registros de una tabla? con un select count(*) from nombre_tabla ya lo tienes. La función Count sirve para contar registros

Comment: gracias amigo por tu respuesta pero no es lo que pido, ya que de esa forma estas recorriendo toda la tabla. Igual digo no se si exista tal metodo al que me refiero solo quiero saber si existe .

Comment: como mucho, según tengas la tabla definida y su comportamiento al añadir o eliminar registros, podrías poner un secuencial y consultar el valor del secuencial del último registro, o añadir un campo que sea el total de registros y hacer lo mismo, consultar el valor del último registro de la tabla.

Comment: gracais amigo por responder ya encontre la solucion. MYSQL tiene una base dedatos que se llama information_schema y en la tabla TABLE seecuentran todas las tablas de las bases de datos y su informacion incluyendo el total de registros de caada tabla. Lo unico que me quedaria es  arreglar una conexion pdo a esa bd y acceder a esa tabla ..

Comment: @user114682 Si la tabla de la que deseas obtener el numero de filas se hacen  inserciones y/o eliminaciones de forma regular, la información de `information_schema.tables` sera solo una aproximación, ya que sus valores se actualizan de forma periodica no directamente al crear o eliminar un registro. Todo dependera de las necesidades del sistema y el contexto. Por lo general la recomendacion es usar `COUNT()`. Este dato puede ser fiable en tablas MyISAM, pero no en tablas InnoDB que puede haber error del 40%-50% segun la documentacion. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tables-table.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No existe un método como tal que permita obtener el número de registros de una tabla MySql de forma directa, lo habitual será hacer una consulta de tipo `SELECT` *sin condiciones* con la función `COUNT()`, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users;
```

o

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE 1;
```

Otra forma, que *depende del diseño del sistema*, es recuperando la ID del último registro guardado. Este método sólo es válido si se está seguro de que no se eliminaron registros, ya que de otro modo el número de registros obtenidos es mayor al existente. La consulta en este caso puede hacerse usando la función `MAX()`:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM users;
```

o

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM users WHERE 1;
```

Este método puede usarse, cuando se hace por ejemplo un *borrado blando*, es decir, hay un campo donde se almacena, por ejemplo, la fecha de eliminación del registro, es decir que el registro no se borra realmente sino que se "marca" lo que es bastante habitual, tanto para preservar los datos como por un tema de eficiencia.

Una tercera opción, es consultar los datos que guarda *MySql* en `information_schema`. La consulta será como la siguiente:

```
TABLE_ROWS FROM information_schema.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'nombre_de_la_base_de_datos' AND TABLE_NAME = 'users'
```

> **Editado**
>
> *En respuesta al comentario de [Xerif](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/38103/xerif)*

Cuidado con esta última opción. Si bien la consulta es más rápida con `information_schema` que realizando un `COUNT()`, cuyo resultado será exacto, `TABLE_ROWS` arroja un resultado aproximado con un margen de error que puede llegar 40%-50% cuando utilizamos un motor diferete de  MyISAM, por ejemplo InnoDB, esto viene reflejado en la [documentación de mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tables-table.html) también existe un hilo, en inglés, sobre la diferencia entre usar [`COUNT()` e information_schema](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151769/mysql-difference-between-using-count-and-information-schema-tables-for-coun) para obtener el número de registros de una tabla.

Comment: gracias amigo por tu respuesta pero si existe un metodo como tal... existe la bd en mysql llamada information_schema en ela tabla TABLES guarda toda la informacion sobre las bd tablas definidas por el usuario incluyendo el numero de registros de cada tabla , puedes comprobarlo . Esto esexelente porque teahorra muchos tener querecorrer toda latabla para conseguir el total.

Comment: Un método muy directo no es, si no me equivoco tienes que hacer una query como esta: `SELECT TABLE_ROWS FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'nombre_de_la_base_de_datos' AND TABLE_NAME = 'users'`, y por eso se suele usar la consulta con `COUNT()`, pero sí, es una forma. Saludos.

Comment: hice la comparacion de tiempo y tarma mucho menos

Comment: @user114682 bueno es saberlo. Tenemos un poco olvidada la información almacenada en `information_schema` y guarda información muy útil. De todos modos, en cuanto a tu pregunta, yo entendí que buscabas algo como `SELECT TOTAL_ROWS() FROM table_name` que no existe claro, pero que ya podía existir ;P. Saludos.

Comment: @orici El tema es que para la inmensa mayoría que utilizamos InnoDB el uso de `information_schema` para saber el numero de filas no es viable en la mayoría de casos, pues sólo almacena una aproximación, aún que todo depende del proyecto y si necesitas un dato certero o una aproximación al dato con bastante margen de error.

Comment: @Xerif pues no tenía ni idea. Es bueno saberlo. Edito la respuesta para puntualizar esta cuestión.

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que utilizar la función `COUNT`

```
SELECT COUNT(ProducID) AS total FROM Productos;
```

Eso te devolverá la cantidad total de productos con el nombre de campo "total"

podes obtener mas información en [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html)